# "Zero frequent items" when using the eclat to mine frequent itemsets

Tags: r, data-mining

So I want to find patterns and "clusters" based on what items that are bought together, and according to the wiki for eclat:

> The Eclat algorithm is used to perform itemset mining. Itemset mining let us find frequent patterns in data like if a consumer buys milk, he also buys bread. This type of pattern is called association rules and is used in many application domains.

Though, when I use the eclat in R, i get "zero frequent items" and "NULL" when when retrieving the results through tidLists. Anyone can see what I am doing wrong?

The full dataset: `https://pastebin.com/8GbjnHK2`

Each row is a transactions, containing different items in the columns. Quick snap of the data:

```
3060615;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
3060612;3060616;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
3020703;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
3002469;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
3062800;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
3061943;3061965;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

The code

```
trans = read.transactions("Transactions.csv", format = "basket", sep = ";")

f <- eclat(trans, parameter = list(supp = 0.1, maxlen = 17, tidLists = TRUE))

dim(tidLists(f))

as(tidLists(f), "list")
```

Could it be due to the data structure? In that case, how should I change it? Furthermore, what do I do to get the suggested itemsets? I couldn't figure that out from the wiki.

EDIT: I used 0.004 for supp, as suggested by @hpesoj626. But it seems like the function is grouping the orders/users and not the items. I don't know how to export the data, so here is a picture of the tidLists:

[image]

Comment: Which part are you having problem with? With the downloaded `8GbjnHK2.txt` file, I get the error `Warning message:
In readLines(file, encoding = encoding) :
  incomplete final line found on '8GbjnHK2.txt'` with `dataset <- read.transactions("8GbjnHK2.txt", sep = ";", rm.duplicates = TRUE)`. Is this your problem?

Comment: No, I fix that part by going on the last row and character in the txt. and simply hit enter, so you have an empty line at the end and save. The problem is that i’m not getting any results out of the eclat function.

Comment: Ah, I see. Perhaps you need to adjust your support? For `supp = 0.004`, I get `180 15840` for `dim(tidLists(f))`.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But it seems like it is grouping the orders instead of items. Do you know why?

Comment: What do you mean it is grouping orders instead of items?

Comment: I uploaded a picture of it on my first post. I did not expect such a list. Maybe I have misunderstood the function. But as I wrote, i'm interested in grouping/clustering the items, based on how frequent they are ordered together.

Comment: You now have a different problem than the one you originally asked about. You should start a different question instead of adding another question that is different than the one you originally asked. However, I think you should use the function `inspect` instead. See my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171872/discussion-between-m-a-and-hpesoj626).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have set your support too high. Try adjusting `supp` say, `supp = .001`, for which we get

```
dim(tidLists(f))

# [1]   928 15840
```

For your data set, the highest support is 0.08239 which is below 0.1. That is why you are getting no results with `supp = 0.1`.

```
inspect(head(sort(f, by = "support"), 10))

#      items             support count
# [1]  {3060620}         0.08239 1305 
# [2]  {3060619}         0.07260 1150 
# [3]  {3061124}         0.05688  901 
# [4]  {3060618}         0.05663  897 
# [5]  {4027039}         0.04975  788 
# [6]  {3060617}         0.04564  723 
# [7]  {3061697}         0.04306  682 
# [8]  {3060619,3060620} 0.03087  489 
# [9]  {3039715}         0.02727  432 
# [10] {3045117}         0.02708  429
```

Comment: I think you mean 0.001 in support, in your first line.