# Capture the output of arules::inspect as data.frame

Tags: r, arules

In ["Zero frequent items" when using the eclat to mine frequent itemsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552493/zero-frequent-items-when-using-the-eclat-to-mine-frequent-itemsets?noredirect=1#comment88118311_50552493), the OP is interested in the groupings/clusterings based on how frequent they are ordered together. This grouping can be inspected by the `arules::inspect` function.

```
library(arules)
dataset <- read.transactions("8GbjnHK2.txt", sep = ";", rm.duplicates = TRUE)
f <- eclat(dataset, 
           parameter = list(
             supp = 0.001, 
             maxlen = 17, 
             tidLists = TRUE))
inspect(head(sort(f, by = "support"), 10))
```

The data set can be downloaded from https://pastebin.com/8GbjnHK2.

However, the output cannot be easily saved to another object as a data frame.

```
out <- inspect(f)
```

So how do we capture the output of `inspect(f)` for use as data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the methods `labels` to extract the associations/groupings and `quality` to extract the quality measures (support and count). We can then use `cbind` to store these into a data frame.

```
out <- cbind(labels = labels(f), quality(f))
head(out)

#              labels  support count
# 1 {3031093,3059242} 0.001010    16
# 2 {3031096,3059242} 0.001073    17
# 3 {3060614,3060615} 0.001010    16
# 4 {3022540,3072091} 0.001010    16
# 5 {3061698,3061700} 0.001073    17
# 6 {3031087,3059242} 0.002778    44
```

Answer (score 0):

Coercing the itemsets to a data.frame also creates the required output.

```
> head(as(f, "data.frame"))
              items     support count
1 {3031093,3059242} 0.001010101    16
2 {3031096,3059242} 0.001073232    17
3 {3060614,3060615} 0.001010101    16
4 {3022540,3072091} 0.001010101    16
5 {3061698,3061700} 0.001073232    17
6 {3031087,3059242} 0.002777778    44
```