# R write.csv2 output showing empty string

Tags: r, csv, apriori

I'm trying to apply the apriori algorithm on a dataset (CSV) which works fine.
After reading transactions and applying apriori I can see the results.

Input file example:

```
transactionid;article
21-348;JG78NF7
42-357;ALL0001
89-786;110845466
...
```

But after writing to CSV this is what is left in my output.csv:

```
""
```

Parameters set are support=0.0001, confidence=0.1
When I increase support to 0.001 my output CSV is actually showing some rows. I thought it's a RAM problem but that's not the case.
Below is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
# load arules library
library(arules)

# read csv file
data <- read.transactions(file='input.csv', format='single', sep=';', cols=1:2)
#summary(data)

#create apriori rules
rules <- apriori(data, parameter=list(support=0.0001, confidence=0.1))
#summary(rules)

#inspect(sort(rules, by='confidence'))
write.csv2(inspect(rules), file='output.csv')
```

There is no error message or anything. Executing with --verbose flag doesn't show an error message. Maybe someone has an idea.

**Specs:**
MacOSX Catalina 10.15.4
R Language (installed via Homebrew) 3.6.3_1
brew version 2.2.11

Comment: inspect only prints it out. maybe you check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554355/capture-the-output-of-arulesinspect-as-data-frame. If you really need the format of inspect, we can write something

Comment: @StupidWolf  But a higher support is giving me results in the output.csv which doesn't makes sense for me but anyways. Your answer is correct. Could you repost your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answered? Thanks :)

Comment: @StupidWolf inspect is giving me lhs and rhs as columns while as(rules, 'data.frame') is not. Is it easy to get lhs and rhs as well?

Comment: Ok I write something for you to get lhs and rhs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inspect()` function only prints, so if you want to get the information for example lhs and rhs, you can follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554355/capture-the-output-of-arulesinspect-as-data-frame) or try something below that gives some information you need:

```
library(arules)
data("Adult")
rules <- apriori(Adult, 
parameter = list(supp = 0.5, conf = 0.9, target = "rules"))

out = data.frame(
lhs=labels(lhs(rules)),
rhs=labels(rhs(rules)),
support = quality(rules)$support,
count=quality(rules)$count)

write.csv(out....)
```